# Embed Java applet

Tags: visualforce

Good morning stackexchange !

In order to avoid human mistake to type errors in forms, I want to embed a Java applet which reads electronic cards for Belgian people.

We have the java applet (.jar) [here](https://www.e-contract.be/maven2/be/fedict/eid-applet/eid-applet-package/1.2.6/). I uploaded the .jar as a Static resources and called it from my vsf page :

```
<applet name="beidapplet" width="600" height="300" code="be.fedict.eid.applet.Applet.class" archive="eid-applet-package-1.2.6.jar" alt="eID applet" codebase="{!URLFOR($Resource.BEIDv2, '')}" >
                            <param name="codebase_lookup" value="true" />
                            <param name="debug" value="true" />
</applet>
```

The applet is loaded and stopped working because of security errors. The error states :

> security manage permission check for java 1.6...
>
> Security Error.
>
> applet not authorized to access smart card. applet not signed ?

The exception is a SecurityException thrown by a

```
securityManager.checkPermission(permission, securityContext);
```

For more details, the error can be found [here](https://github.com/e-Contract/eid-applet/blob/master/eid-applet-core/src/main/java/be/fedict/eid/applet/Applet.java#L545). This is executed on IE 11.0.9 with a jre1.8.0_65.

Is it something specific from Salesforce that I'm missing ? Or should I ask the java forum ?

Comment: Looks like a Java issue e.g. [Oracle Java 7 Update 51 blocks unsigned Java applets by default](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/oracle-java-7-update-51-blocks-unsigned-java-applets-by-default/).

Comment: Indeed Java increased its policy and I did the steps in order to make the site as an exception to run all java applications. Of course it requires a human action which is not likeable.

To avoid that, I should add a signature. Is it possible within the Salesforce org ? I have little experience with that..

Comment: I just tested it with jarsigner -verify and it states my .jar is verified.

Comment: Probably best to ask on a Java forum.