# Blocked Java Application

Tags: visualforce

I've an issue on java applet being blocked on my vsf page.

First of all, the java applet is only a EId card reader I/O on a vsf page. No web service, a local applet. Just to easy the filling of fields into my vsf page.

In my [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97985/embed-java-applet) I realized I didn't link the appropriate libraries to each other files. *What could go wrong ?*

So I tried a different approach. I put all the needed .jar files into a zip as a static resource and the applet loads from there, as following :

```
                        <script>
                            var attributes = {
                                codebase : "{!URLFOR($Resource.eidApplet,'/')}",
                                code :'be.fedict.eid.applet.Applet.class',
                                archive : 'eid-applet-package-1.2.6.jar,eid-applet-service-1.2.6.jar,eid-applet-service-cdi-1.2.6.jar,eid-applet-service-signer-1.2.6.jar,eid-applet-service-spi-1.2.6.jar,eid-applet-shared-1.2.6.jar',
                                width :400,
                                height :300,
                                mayscript :'true'
                            };
                            var parameters = {
                                AppletService : 'identification-service',
                                BackgroundColor : '#ffffff',
                                codebase_lookup : 'true'
                            };
                            var version = '1.6';
                            deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
                        </script>
```

All these .jar are signed and verified by. Signed from the company which developed the applet, and the certificate is publicly accepted (the cert can be seen [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates#godaddyrootg2ca))

So here's the trick, when I go to my vsf page it displays an error message.
[image]

But how come it's blocked even if I put the location in the Exception Site List ? I already tried on other websites (you can see the CMP Wassup tab on my browser) and it worked. Not on Salesforce. Hence why I'm asking it here. Why is it blocked ? Is there something specific I'm missing ?

Thank you.

*Edit*

Don't mind the blur on the URL. My hand slipped. The url matches the second one in my exception site list

*Edit 2*

In regards of Vsf pages not loading on the same domain than the org, ... well I tried (overkill ?) with other domain names, but the error remains.

[image: java app blocked with overkill exception site list]

Comment: IMHO : Raise a support case with Salesforce.com. They should be able to help you.

Comment: Your VF page is not being served from cs17.... it has a different domain, which is why the exception is not being applied.

Comment: I updated the answer